# how to call fucntion which contain nested dictionary from another python script

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I am trying to get the nested dictionary data from another python script.
As an example below

```
main.py

class data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.result()

    def result(self):
        self.output_data = {}

    def get_list(self):
        return self.output_data

--------------------------------------------------------
script.py
from main import data

class communix():

   def __init__(self):

   def new_data(self):
   want to fetch the nested dictionary from get_list function
```

Comment: `data` is a class, not an object. Unless you instantiate it, there won't be any data.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few modifications in your code, there are some hints I'd like you to note:

1. In python, use CamelCase naming convention for your class names.
2. You can mix your two `result()` and `get_list()` methods into one method.
3. Why don't you use inheritence in your second class?

So, regarding points mentionned above, this code worked for me:

```
    main.py


    class Data():
        def __init__(self):
            self.result()

        def result(self):
            self.output_data = {'data': 'sample data'}
            return self.output_data
```

---

```
    script.py


    from main import Data
    
    class Communix(Data):
        
        def new_data(self):
            data_extracted = data_object.result()
            return data_extracted

   data_object = Communix()
   print(data_object.new_data())
```

output:

```
   >>> {'data': 'sample data'}
```

I hope it helped you.